# tinymce with jframe and form plugin

Tags: jquery, forms, plugins, tinymce, jframe

I manage to call TinyMce editor with Jframe ,but for now I have a problem:

textarea is not update on insert or update click button .
For each event jFrame take control and I cannot call any event before submit or click or anything else.

Anyone have experiece this ?

Answer (score 0):

For every one ,I find the solution :

on jFrame caller page init TinyMCE :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/tinymce/tiny_mce_gzip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--

tinyMCE_GZ.init({
    plugins : "safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,ccSimpleUploader,mediaservice",
    themes : 'advanced',
    languages : 'en',
    disk_cache : true,
    debug : false
 });
//add a function
function loadEditor() {

tinyMCE.init({
                        mode : "exact",
                        elements : "wysiwyg",
                        theme : "advanced",
                        skin : "o2k7",
                        skin_variant : "silver",                                
                        plugins : "safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,ccSimpleUploader,mediaservice",
                        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "code,fullscreen,preview,|newdocument,|,search,|,undo,redo,|,cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,bold,italic,underline,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,bullist,numlist",
................................

         });


} 

$(document).ready(function(){

//on ajax event complete
$("#invoices_target").ajaxComplete(function() {    
  loadEditor();
});

//--><!]]>
</script>
```

then in called page :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
$(document).ready(function(){

});
function saveMCE() {
tinyMCE.triggerSave();
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true,'wysiwyg');
}
//--><!]]>
</script>
```

then put the saveMCE() function on "onClick" button event in your form :

```
<form id="recordSettings" method="post" name="settings">
    <textarea id="wysiwyg" rows="8" cols="47" name="wysiwyg"></textarea>
    <input onclick="javascript:saveMCE();"  type="button" name="insert" />
</form>
```

That's all,
for me this work fine ,hope for you too.